# How to deal with corrupted files that were created but IOException occured?

Tags: java, io, inputstream, ioexception, fileinputstream

Could you please suggest how to deal with these situations ? I understand that in the second example, it is very rare that it would happen on unix, is it ? If access rights are alright. Also the file wouldn't be even created. I don't understand why the IOException is there, either it is created or not, why do we have to bother with IOException ?

But in the first example, there will be a corrupted zombie file. Now if you tell the user to upload it again, the same thing may happen. If you can't do that, and the inputstream has no marker. You loose your data ? I really don't like how this is done in Java, I hope the new IO in Java 7 is better

Is it usual to delete it

```
public void inputStreamToFile(InputStream in, File file) throws SystemException {

    OutputStream out;
    try {
        out = new FileOutputStream(file);
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        throw new SystemException("Temporary file created : " + file.getAbsolutePath() + " but not found to be populated", e);
    }

    boolean fileCorrupted = false;
    int read = 0;
    byte[] bytes = new byte[1024];

    try {
        while ((read = in.read(bytes)) != -1) {
            out.write(bytes, 0, read);
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        fileCorrupted = true;
        logger.fatal("IO went wrong for file : " + file.getAbsolutePath(), e);
    } finally {
        IOUtils.closeQuietly(in);
        IOUtils.closeQuietly(out);

                    if(fileCorrupted) {
        ???
                    }
    }
}


public File createTempFile(String fileId, String ext, String root) throws SystemException {

    String fileName = fileId + "." + ext;

    File dir = new File(root);

    if (!dir.exists()) {
        if (!dir.mkdirs())
            throw new SystemException("Directory " + dir.getAbsolutePath() + " already exists most probably");
    }

    File file = new File(dir, fileName);

    boolean fileCreated = false;
    boolean fileCorrupted = false;
    try {
        fileCreated = file.createNewFile();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        fileCorrupted = true;
        logger.error("Temp file " + file.getAbsolutePath() + " creation fail", e);
    } finally {

        if (fileCreated)
            return file;
        else if (!fileCreated && !fileCorrupted)
            throw new SystemException("File " + file.getAbsolutePath() + " already exists most probably");
        else if (!fileCreated && fileCorrupted) {

        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I really don't like how this is done in Java, I hope the new IO in Java 7 is better

I'm not sure how Java is different than any other programming language/environment in the way you are using it:

- a client sends some data to your over the wire
- as you read it, you write it to a local file

Regardless of the language/tools/environment, it's possible for the connection to be interrupted or lost, for the client to go away, for the disk to die, or for any other error to occur. I/O errors can occur in any and all environments.

What you can do in this situation is highly dependent on the situation and the error that occured. For example, is the data structured in some way where you could ask the user to resume uploading from record 1000, for example? However, there is no single solution that fits all here.

Comment: I do understand that in the network stack problems may arise. But I mostly deal with streams to a local socket or buffer stream and because it has all the same interface it throws IOExceptions and developer doesn't know if he deals with no space left on device or what exactly. For instance IOException when creating file shouldn't imho be there. It either creates it or not, or the developer should be aware of what has happened, but I can't find anywhere what are the causes of IOException in that case...

Comment: It's nice that the exception tells me what was wrong. But mostly a developer is aware of the problems that may arise and can react up on it in the catch block

Comment: @lisak - how does the developer become aware of any problems? Either you return a status code from each operation, throw an exception, or require a second explicit operation to verify the first. I've seen far too much C code where the developer didn't check the return code of an operation. And as for a second explicit operation ... if the developer can't be bothered to check a return code, it's unlikely that s/he'll do that second operation. Checked exceptions force you to become aware of what's happening.

Comment: I meant that in most cases s/he is aware of what problem the exception represents, but creating a file on unix never yields any unexpected problem, at least I've never seen one in 6 years. May I rely on that with JVM ?

Comment: @lisak - You've never experienced a hard disk error?  You've never experienced a full filesystem?

Comment: Not hard disk error, but No space left and access politics are the only ones . If these are the only cases, I really shouldn't have to deal with it at all

Comment: should I then really focus on exception handling of streams from internet socket only ? Like multipart requests ? And just throw the other IOExceptions cause if I take care of enough space on device, there is 0,001% probability that they occur

Comment: In regard to Multipart request, the stream is copied to memory or to a temporary file, so that there theoretically should also be 0,001% probability of IOException